# ASUS UX391FA - unable to boot/black screen after BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, laptop, bios, asus

Whenever I power up the pc the ASUS logo appears then the pc is stuck instead of booting Windows: the screen seems to be on but black, no cursor, mouse and keyboard not responding, back-illumination of the keyboard not present (it usually lights up at the windows login page).
The problem does not appear every time, there is like a 50% chance that this happens, apparently random.

When it happens I force the shut down holding the power button for 15 seconds and boot passing through BIOS, and everything usually works fine and I can enter windows; sometimes, but not always, forcing shut down and restarting is sufficient without passing through BIOS.

I updated the BIOS and did a clean windows install but the problem repeated unaltered after a while.

What can be the reason for this issue? How to solve?

My pc is an ASUS UX391FA laptop with Windows 10.